# How can I detect the cancel request in C++ grpc?

Tags: grpc, cancellation-token, cancellationtokensource, grpc-c++, grpc-c#

I want to exchange a data with grpc.

While doing this, I am trying to establish a connection between c++ and c#. I created a server with C++. I have a client with C#. I can simply make request response examples. I want to provide continuous data flow by server streaming. However, I want to cancel the stream by sending a message from the client to stop the stream. I thought of doing this by C# using cancellationTokenSource. On the C++ side, I am trying to understand whether this cancel request came with IsCancelled, but I could not succeed. I wonder if I should send information with a different method instead of cancellationtoken from c#? How to trigger Iscancelled?

```
if (context->IsCancelled()) {
            //I am trying to understand cancel request in c++
            return grpc::Status(grpc::StatusCode::CANCELLED, "RPC is cancelled by the client");
        }


in C#:

 _token = new CancellationTokenSource();
using var response= client.task(request,cancellationToken: _token.Token );

 public void button() // I send Cancel request
    {
        _token.Cancel();
    }
```

Comment: I think overall your approach sounds fine. The client can request cancelling the call by token.Cancel() and the server should be able to see that status. Note that there might be other reasons why the call gets cancelled (e.g. the call deadline has elapsed) and you won't be able to tell on the server side what exactly caused the cancellation. If you shall need a more advanced "protocol" for stopping the call for various reasons, you can actually use a bidi streaming call and the client can control server's behavior via sending different request messages and/or closing the request stream.